# Rspec Validation testing (Mongoid )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mongoid

I got a problem when i testing validations in rails with mongoid
This is for example my Person Model  and my Rspec test.

```
class Person
    include Mongoid::Document

    validates :first_name , :presence => true
    validates :last_name , :presence => true

end



 [ :last_name, :first_name ].each do |attr|
  it "must have a #{attr}" do
    p = Person.new
    p.send("#{attr}=","")
    p.should_not be_valid
    p.errors[attr].should == [ "can't be blank" ] 
  end
end
```

But this tests fail because the return value is  ["can't be blank", "can't be blank"]

> ```
>   expected: ["can't be blank"]
>         got: ["can't be blank", "can't be blank"]
> ```

Why are 2 Errors in this record??
i test this issue with many models and other validation rules. I got everytime the same result

Thx for help

Eric

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting one of your fields to empty string and the other retains default value of `nil`. That's why both of your validations fail each time.

Comment: but why i get only one error when i test this issue on the rails console manual () ..    p = Person.new   p.valid? p.error[:first_name]   got  => ["can't be blank"]

Comment: hmm, thats confusing ... on my console i got only one error each value(first and lastname) hmm can there be an error or failconfiguration in my testing environment ... -.-